# Java download "google-formatted" image

Tags: java, image, download, google-image-search

I need download image from google search (only preview - the small image when you type to search space)

The URL looks like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhQSExQUFRUWGBgYGRgXGRobHhccGhgaGhgcGRsaHCggGB8mHyAYIjEhJSkrLi4uFyAzODMsNygtLisBCgoKDQwNFw8QFzcdHyU3LCwsLiw3MC8xNywyLzA3LDc3MjcuLjc3MjczNyw0ODc0LSszKzc3NzQsNzI3KzE4Mv/AABEIAKYAsAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAADAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwQFAgEGB//EAD8QAAIBAgQCCAQDBgUEAwAAAAECEQADBBIhMUFRBRMiMmFxgZFCUqGxI3LBFDNigpLwBkNTotFjsrPhc8LS/8QAFgEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEC/8QAHBEBAAICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERMVECIWES/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9xooooCiiigKKK8NB7RSr+IVBmdgo2kmNTsPE1JexjRmACJxa7p7LueO8etBfNc3byqJZgo5kgD3NZYJbjdueUW1PlsSOPGlXMEytbcJZRs0SAXbtKwksYJ4b8qDRfpO0BPWKR4GftNeW+lbJ2uL66fevbdi5xuacggEfU169i5wue6g/8UDLGKR+46tHykHfbamzWLdwjPdhhZudWkw6R+8bSDJA7h1jj40woV4XU5lG6wezCfpQa80VmYfFsZgpdA3y9l180J/UeVWYfFK8gHtDdToVnmN/+aB9FeTXtAUUUUBRRRQFFFFAUUUUBUF/GEyLeXTvO3cSN52zEcgfMikYrHhjkllTXtDe4ZgpbjjzPtMEhuFwchc6gKsZLY2WNp+ZvoOHMhOuG6zugmRBuvvB/wBJdMvCDoNAYNP6OsLGZhmur2WZjJkcR8oOh0A3FaNRYjsXFf4WhG8/gb37P8w5UD7t9UjMyrmMCSBJOwE7mk9KfuyflKt7MDXnSPR4vBQWZcrBgVgHTxiR6RVGKtZkZZjMpE8pETQI6VxvU2mcZZGwYwCSYAEAkkmABGpNT9EdLG81xSmUpHGYlnXK3JgUmOTLzqvDMt20hIBDqpg6jUAwedPS2BsAKCbDavdbxAnwVRp5SWPqaoW6pYrIzAAkTqASQCRuAYOvgeVTdG6oW3zMzTz7UA+0V1awYF17wJzOiIRpEIXK8N+2fYUBj7aZS7jugnMNGHkRqKgTBuqhrg6wntEgxcQmNFYRmAEDgdONW3u3cCfCkO3ifgH/ANvQc9HvdUEAsASQACRqTsPofY0EVjGlRmYh7f8AqDQrG/WL8McSPUCK0VaalxGF1zocr8+DDk44+e4+lQ28V1ZCqrD5rIElP40jdN9OPCCCCG1RXNtwwDAggiQRqCDsQeNdUBRRRQFFFFATWdj78krmKqom4+0DgoPM+GoHmKqxl7IsgS2yjmTsP75VFhrEtlmVtmWMfvLm5PgF+5Hy6h1ZwOcTcECIRBp1Y4RHxeI22HGW2LxVhbuGSe63z+B5MPruOQfjL4RC5BMcB4mPQePCkWbiYi0rDVHAI/Qg8COYoIOmugOvZ2zIM9tbTBrefQOW+YEHUgEbTNa1+0GUq2xEHh9eFIw98q3V3Nz3G+fwPJvDjEjiAnEYzMCVbKmxuRJJ2i2PiPjr4TQd2ccFWLh7YlYA1fLGqqNTIIOnOunxbxmCADncYIPoCR7VnmyVcOoNpXhHbvXG1/DZiZCwSw1nR+EVppgUBzRmbgW7RHkTMelB850l0g64S+yX7YNtbrKVtuwBQl0GfPlZdMp0Gh4U3of/ABL+0YZcSrdSrKSVu2LnZga9rMoKj5tjzrbsKM91DqJBjwZf1Iauukh+Gy/NCejEKY9Catx81XexJ0ZiHFpAFRwAATbuA6x2pB0BngCapbpFADOYMATkIhj4KPiPlO4p1/BoxllE/Nsf6hrWbicMzNknrESGZbnzbqFfmO9rPw6iag0cFaKrLRnY5mjXU8J4gaCdNqzcd0Aty71uYqS1piIGvVZo1njPGfKnYfEFZjM6jvI37y3/APsb/oTtVN3GiF6uHZhKwdI+YngB/wCqDvFYjLCqMztML5bljwApLYAgZg34u+c8TyI+Tw4eetPwuGySSczHvNz/AOANYHD60ro3pO3fDm0wYI5QkEEEgA6EHbWgnw1/Kc0QjNDr/pXCf+1p35kH4tNQVn9I2gs3CJWMt0cGTmfFdfQnwpmBcibbEkpEE/Ep7p8TuD4jxoLaKKKArw17XF+4FUsdgCT6a0GX0h22Jyz1cLbGom63GRtlECRzblTMNZuWVyg9ao5wH8SSNG18AfOucGhzWw26qbj/AJ7h031+f2qzEYlUKhjGdgo31J8qDkXbd0Mhg8GQ6EeY39aotoAAAAANAByqOw1rEItxYZTOVhod4lTuPT60jFvdtgKpD5uyp+NdyTyeBJ4bazvQedIut0MrT1SmGjd24InkdyOOnOjAqysovxnj8M/CAB3RwDxudJ1iAIHvRuRz2e7b7KqdwfjZgdZ3APmfirQv2Q6lW1B/sEcjxmg6vWQylWEgiCKTgHJBVjLIcpPPk3qINcWL5Ui3cMk91/n8DwDffccQPMWcjLd4Hsv5E9lvQ/RjQdRF8/xoPUoxn6MPevcb3rQjd/aFJ5V5iRFy03iyz4MJj3Va8u630Hyo59yoH60D8VfCKWIJA4DcnYAeJOnrXGCslV7WrHtMRzO8eA2HlSnGe4F+G32j4sR2R6CSfNfGmYrEZYVRLnYchxLcloE9IxKhf3vwkcBxLfwcxx4axUmEHVF3O8zfEe1xOS76cgeIM6eFwwUGe0zd5jx/4A4DhSOkyEi7IDJ/uXivmdI8QKCxWkaag/Wks1u0CTlTMZPDMT9ztWfgrzk9XbGVCM6M4M5DGirM6T8URmXQ6gXWcIqmTLN8zan7QPIAUHBuXH7q5F+ZxJI8E4evtUFqyLJmSTagFm3NpttdoUjhHcq7CdK2rjKqEnMrMsqwDBWCtBI1gkT5ivcYgzoxGhm23iG2n1H+40Fte1J0a3YAO6yp810n1EH1qugKi6XYdXB2Yqp32JE7DlOtW1LixLWhwzk+ysR9aBHRuJRzcdXRpeOywOigAbGqsVhluDK4kTMVNgLCXLSMyhplhmAMZiW5eP0pjdHpwBH5WYfY0HeCwiWlCW1CqCSANhJk/U1Fi7hLXGXdQLaeDORmPp2PY86q/Y2+G7cHnlb7rWdbS5KwUcNdc6gqeyCASwMaERGXjQaX7ChVRHcACkaEAciNaX+Lb/6q89A489lb0j1pgv3Bvbn8rA+0xXhxwHeS4P5SQPVZFB6HS8pXfmNQynhI3U8RSg3+Td7QYEKx2cRqpjZo99xsQOL16y5EuqtsDOR/SYJ8tq9uo2Uqw65PDRx7QCRvIg7acaDhnOSDq1p0nxEgBj5qZ8waa17K9598oRQOJOrADXjnA9Kzoa7nVSD2Tbd2EaEEqGWJ6xTw0EMdpEMvh0h2Nt1DFiw7KhjAUuCTCATrJ9KCy2TbUIAGutLEbCT3mJ4KNvYU1AtlS7sJPedoEnh5DgB48amw2aCUEFtWu3ARPkmhgcASAJ48ewbKNL3Az79tgW/lUbegoGi879xco+Zx9k394ruzglUhjLN8zan04L6AVyuPX4VuN5I33IFejEudrTD8zKPsT/YoI2XIY/0nBH5LmntM/wBNaprHxtm675CbadZbdDAZ52idViJbnuapwtp7iK5uuMyq0LlESJgHLJGvPhQd2ejUVgygyM0SSQMxJaBwkmjpVwLTyyrAkFiAAV7Q38QK6OATjmbzZj9JimW8FbGoRQdpgT770EvRuKR7lzIcykW7kjbtgiAdj3Z341pVk9GEk2W3BsnUbGCnCtagKkxY/Es+DN/42quouknC9W5k5XGwJPaBXZQSd6Drolps2iOKL9qku9HubjOHMG5bcCW0CrlZY2g7xtXWBxD5MotN2Sw1KqNGMDvHhFUFrx2W2vmSfsBQWVl4TvWztrfGumuefsCaeLV073QPyIAfQsWH0rO/ZQD2mdst2DmaARcEbLA+LgBQbTOBuQPOpz0ha+dT5GftXa4G3vkWeZEn601iqgnRQPICgm/bA21u43OUy/8AfE+lfNf4w6X/AGOz1q4RbhDKOrR8rHMYUgIpntZR68dju4rpBzC2QMz6KzyAebBd2AGvAHTXWlWsGtowC168+pa5E/mIUAIo8B4DWtcaiYmYvwZ/QVy9dtOL1lbbZ1fqmuF2KtrDkqNNIB1BKkcK0L/ZS8xSBcXKtvSXaGB0Xi0qNOC0nF4bvkMSyA9ucpa64AABB7IUHRdpYfLXd/DqGZnlgjZWzEmEYAggkyuUwZEQM1ScjvC2wwnKl2NCc7TIicyuOyfA6irEvBBHUugHyqCPQLqfakG12glyc2yXR2S3gSPiHI6HluA/rLid4dYvNRDAeK/F/L7VB0OkbfFsvg4Kx5hgIpyXlbVWBHgQaLN5XBykMNiOXgRwPga8fB2yZKLPOBPvQKvn8W0PB/sK86EWMPYHEWrY9kFZ+NsAG51ZZSlvKMrNGe4YWdYkQpPg4q9MI6AKl0wIHbVTAGgAyhf1oE9J4K496xcR8q282ZeDSUgxxIAYDUd/jsdMVHN4cLbf1L958KLmLdQS1ptBPZZTt5kUE/RZlbGkfhsY5SUrVrH6IILIAGGSyoOZSD2zIgkQ3dMxPCtigKl6UH4TECSsMBzKnN+lVV4woI8I4z3FGxyup5hhz46g+4pfTOKe3bLoATIGuwk6k6jQeJApFjsFP+mTaM/K0G2Z/pHqa1HYAEkwBxOkUHGFulkViCpZQSDIKkiYIIBBHjUePtgMZOVbilGbbKyyUP1b1C039rZ/3SyPnaQvpxbzGnjXN3owMPxGLtwJ0CncFVGgg7bnmTQLwuPa4oNtROzM2igjeBuw3IOgI1mqLeBE5nJdubbD8q7L9TzJqS3iCpLtoNFvD5WGzj+Ejc8oPA1biMTEKkM52HAD5mjYfegka9+M+XtPARV4LHadidwJKg88ginEdUjN33ManQux0UeAnQDgK46Hw+VXbdndmZtJbWBtsIAgcKYvbu/w2/q5+2Ue5bwFWcji5ZypbtzmJdcx2LGc7H3E+VMAHXODqHRTHAwWDT6FR6V7f1u2xyDt66KJ/qb2ov6XbZ5h185AYfY1ArDWwVay+uTTXcqdUad50ieamu7F0owt3DM91/m8DwDffhRjuwVujZdG/IdyfIwfATVF60HBVhIP978PMUC7+DVjmghvmXRvfj5GRSmvPbnOA6AEl10IA4svH+X2rqxeZCLdwzPcf5vBuTffhxFKxt4MSD+7SC5jvH4UHMzuPIcaCfB3BcKQQcxN1/4QNEVuR8D8jcq2DWfZ6PBm4wK3WMkqYIjuryYAaQZG9N624nfGcfMg1jmV4/yz5UGb0b0rde6EdAo7UwG4FhmzHTLoBtMmZ4VpdJa2yvzkJ/UYPlpPtT7N5XEqQw8P15HwqPGXocncWlLRzdtEA5mJ0/jFA7B6tcfm0DyUR7TmPqasqfBWciKpMkDU8ydWPvNUUBRRRQZfSlogyACrjq3kxEnsNI10JI/mFGBs5v3p6x1MMDooI4hdhIgiZOtaF62GBU6giCPOstXZTJkvbADwNblvXKwHxEa7ccwG4oK+kcWbaqwEy6JvEB2Cz4xO1I/w/wBK/tNoXChTbsncSAYJ2kTB5EEVo23DAEEEHUEbGkYrEZSEQAudhwA4s0bD70E3SUhl6sA3ojKdmXj1nIcjvJ03NTdGxaBjMy6ZxHbtkcCBunIDYbSNtTC4cKN8zHVmO7H9ByHCucThQxzAlWGzD7EbMPA/SgiwN8JYGXKzAlQAdCxY5dRwMg+VaGEs5FC7niTxJ1J9TXzuJDC8b0FAnZdra5ldjuzoRIyD4h8zyRArXw2MZlzAJdHO2d+GgYx9eFa5bDrYm+5+VEHuWP8AxRjtMjcnXXkD2f1j1qfB4wZrhK3AS+3VuYhVG6gg+ho6Uxg6p4FwsFLLFu4e0vaXZeYGlZGkw0qPAHKGtHe3AE8UPdP0In+GhsWxEqkL8zsoBG4IgkxHOKy8WcxFwk3cmjBRlthDE5j8cRmiTEba6hbjb4uIwBAt/FcOw/8Aj5t/FsDzNIwFshkW4CqD9zPxHnc5XI4HxO8hdCxhTIa4QxGwAhV5ZRz8T9Kdesq6lWEg/wBjyPjQMbbTU1j9C9Mm+wVlCk2luCGDbhc0x3dWgTEwSNjVti8yMLdwzPcf5vBuTffhxqsigkx9hADcllYa5k7x5CNm5QQaiwVtywR4JEXHYcWI7KkbaROh+FdppuJxGY5olUMIB/mXOHovPnJ+HW3CWMq6mWOrHmTvHhwA5UFFFFFAUUUUBUuLwxaGUw6yVPDXcHmp0nyB4VVRQYX7b1chBvOZD/knixj4NQdPMaExq4OwFBM5i2rN8x/QchXGJwknOhCuBE8GHysOI5cuFSYZypYIpndrJIkfxWidCDy2/KZFA/F2Ha7ZKkhVLF4YidIVSo0YEknXbKOdOxd7Iuglicqjmx29OJ8BXeHxCuJUzwPAg8iDqD4Gp7Zz3S3w2+yPFviPoIA82oIOjuibqHt3ywDTuwkazorKFmeR29psN/h1lYnOslSoaCSJIKkSfhg8dc3gKu6ZS/KG1myw2cLlk7RBbUHcCCNzvpDs9xcNNwgXRaGYr8+WCR/NQSf4Z6MNvC2F6y4T1ay2YmZ1mHLa61ojBGIa7db1C/8AjVaegCKABooiPIeNJ6PxoupmylTLKVaJBUkHYxwoJui8EnVoSskADtSx7OnxcdK0jG1S4AQHXk7fUz+tQ27WIN8FiwQXHIIIAKZFCqVG8sWMnXsnXUUFvR7Zc1k/BBHihnL7QV/lpd6zcOIRhmFsKc3b0J1gZPWc2/ZAGk13jlyxdEym/ih72g3jQ+lVNeUDMSAN5JEe9BzftK6lWEg8P7286ybuLIm0zdgSDd2mPg016yNyPTtaB+JxJYT2ktnbQh7ngg3Xz0PlvTcNhCSGcBQvctjZPE8Gbx2HDiSHuDw5JDlcsCET5F8hpmOk8tuc314BXtAUUUUBRRRQFFFFAVPicKrgTMjYgwV8iNqoooMXHWXUZoLOBC3EgMOALrswG5AB/LTMFeKoAoF1R8Sd7xLKTvMzB9K1qmv4NGMkEN8ykqfca+lAW8YjaBhPI6H2OtL6R7oX5mUa8RmkjbkDXNzCvEZluDlcUT7rH2qK/gmlItuADP4VzbsmCEchRrHA0G0VB3rjD4dUGVFCqNgBArO6xh2c2IU762w8eqqR9a8W62zXL5nQRZj65IHmaCrDt+LdXmEf3DLH+w+9Ov4lE7zAeuvtWU2GcuDlvEBWHbuKgOqx+6bXZtxx4bVXbwbju9Xb37q5j7nT6Gg6fFkiVSB89zsr7HtH2FZ+AssdAOsynsXHEW1GkZEG8bA8l71aiYFZzNLtzcz7Dur6AbCqgKCbD4QKcxJZ/mP2A2UeA9ZqkCvaKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooP/2Q==
```

Very strange beginning of URL, I can download image if they are in normal format :

```
http://.../picture.jpeg
```

by this code:

```
        Image image = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlAdr);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
        {
           out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directoryToSave);
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
```

I can't figure out how to change code to download URL above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not URL. This is image data with header informing how it was encoded (base64). So you simply need to get rid of `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part and convert `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ....` part to bytes. Then you can write them anywhere you want since they represent image.

Example:

```
String dataUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhQSExQUFRUWGBgYGRgXGRobHhccGhgaGhgcGRsaHCggGB8mHyAYIjEhJSkrLi4uFyAzODMsNygtLisBCgoKDQwNFw8QFzcdHyU3LCwsLiw3MC8xNywyLzA3LDc3MjcuLjc3MjczNyw0ODc0LSszKzc3NzQsNzI3KzE4Mv/AABEIAKYAsAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAADAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwQFAgEGB//EAD8QAAIBAgQCCAQDBgUEAwAAAAECEQADBBIhMUFRBRMiMmFxgZFCUqGxI3LBFDNigpLwBkNTotFjsrPhc8LS/8QAFgEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEC/8QAHBEBAAICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERMVECIWES/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9xooooCiiigKKK8NB7RSr+IVBmdgo2kmNTsPE1JexjRmACJxa7p7LueO8etBfNc3byqJZgo5kgD3NZYJbjdueUW1PlsSOPGlXMEytbcJZRs0SAXbtKwksYJ4b8qDRfpO0BPWKR4GftNeW+lbJ2uL66fevbdi5xuacggEfU169i5wue6g/8UDLGKR+46tHykHfbamzWLdwjPdhhZudWkw6R+8bSDJA7h1jj40woV4XU5lG6wezCfpQa80VmYfFsZgpdA3y9l180J/UeVWYfFK8gHtDdToVnmN/+aB9FeTXtAUUUUBRRRQFFFFAUUUUBUF/GEyLeXTvO3cSN52zEcgfMikYrHhjkllTXtDe4ZgpbjjzPtMEhuFwchc6gKsZLY2WNp+ZvoOHMhOuG6zugmRBuvvB/wBJdMvCDoNAYNP6OsLGZhmur2WZjJkcR8oOh0A3FaNRYjsXFf4WhG8/gb37P8w5UD7t9UjMyrmMCSBJOwE7mk9KfuyflKt7MDXnSPR4vBQWZcrBgVgHTxiR6RVGKtZkZZjMpE8pETQI6VxvU2mcZZGwYwCSYAEAkkmABGpNT9EdLG81xSmUpHGYlnXK3JgUmOTLzqvDMt20hIBDqpg6jUAwedPS2BsAKCbDavdbxAnwVRp5SWPqaoW6pYrIzAAkTqASQCRuAYOvgeVTdG6oW3zMzTz7UA+0V1awYF17wJzOiIRpEIXK8N+2fYUBj7aZS7jugnMNGHkRqKgTBuqhrg6wntEgxcQmNFYRmAEDgdONW3u3cCfCkO3ifgH/ANvQc9HvdUEAsASQACRqTsPofY0EVjGlRmYh7f8AqDQrG/WL8McSPUCK0VaalxGF1zocr8+DDk44+e4+lQ28V1ZCqrD5rIElP40jdN9OPCCCCG1RXNtwwDAggiQRqCDsQeNdUBRRRQFFFFATWdj78krmKqom4+0DgoPM+GoHmKqxl7IsgS2yjmTsP75VFhrEtlmVtmWMfvLm5PgF+5Hy6h1ZwOcTcECIRBp1Y4RHxeI22HGW2LxVhbuGSe63z+B5MPruOQfjL4RC5BMcB4mPQePCkWbiYi0rDVHAI/Qg8COYoIOmugOvZ2zIM9tbTBrefQOW+YEHUgEbTNa1+0GUq2xEHh9eFIw98q3V3Nz3G+fwPJvDjEjiAnEYzMCVbKmxuRJJ2i2PiPjr4TQd2ccFWLh7YlYA1fLGqqNTIIOnOunxbxmCADncYIPoCR7VnmyVcOoNpXhHbvXG1/DZiZCwSw1nR+EVppgUBzRmbgW7RHkTMelB850l0g64S+yX7YNtbrKVtuwBQl0GfPlZdMp0Gh4U3of/ABL+0YZcSrdSrKSVu2LnZga9rMoKj5tjzrbsKM91DqJBjwZf1Iauukh+Gy/NCejEKY9Catx81XexJ0ZiHFpAFRwAATbuA6x2pB0BngCapbpFADOYMATkIhj4KPiPlO4p1/BoxllE/Nsf6hrWbicMzNknrESGZbnzbqFfmO9rPw6iag0cFaKrLRnY5mjXU8J4gaCdNqzcd0Aty71uYqS1piIGvVZo1njPGfKnYfEFZjM6jvI37y3/APsb/oTtVN3GiF6uHZhKwdI+YngB/wCqDvFYjLCqMztML5bljwApLYAgZg34u+c8TyI+Tw4eetPwuGySSczHvNz/AOANYHD60ro3pO3fDm0wYI5QkEEEgA6EHbWgnw1/Kc0QjNDr/pXCf+1p35kH4tNQVn9I2gs3CJWMt0cGTmfFdfQnwpmBcibbEkpEE/Ep7p8TuD4jxoLaKKKArw17XF+4FUsdgCT6a0GX0h22Jyz1cLbGom63GRtlECRzblTMNZuWVyg9ao5wH8SSNG18AfOucGhzWw26qbj/AJ7h031+f2qzEYlUKhjGdgo31J8qDkXbd0Mhg8GQ6EeY39aotoAAAAANAByqOw1rEItxYZTOVhod4lTuPT60jFvdtgKpD5uyp+NdyTyeBJ4bazvQedIut0MrT1SmGjd24InkdyOOnOjAqysovxnj8M/CAB3RwDxudJ1iAIHvRuRz2e7b7KqdwfjZgdZ3APmfirQv2Q6lW1B/sEcjxmg6vWQylWEgiCKTgHJBVjLIcpPPk3qINcWL5Ui3cMk91/n8DwDffccQPMWcjLd4Hsv5E9lvQ/RjQdRF8/xoPUoxn6MPevcb3rQjd/aFJ5V5iRFy03iyz4MJj3Va8u630Hyo59yoH60D8VfCKWIJA4DcnYAeJOnrXGCslV7WrHtMRzO8eA2HlSnGe4F+G32j4sR2R6CSfNfGmYrEZYVRLnYchxLcloE9IxKhf3vwkcBxLfwcxx4axUmEHVF3O8zfEe1xOS76cgeIM6eFwwUGe0zd5jx/4A4DhSOkyEi7IDJ/uXivmdI8QKCxWkaag/Wks1u0CTlTMZPDMT9ztWfgrzk9XbGVCM6M4M5DGirM6T8URmXQ6gXWcIqmTLN8zan7QPIAUHBuXH7q5F+ZxJI8E4evtUFqyLJmSTagFm3NpttdoUjhHcq7CdK2rjKqEnMrMsqwDBWCtBI1gkT5ivcYgzoxGhm23iG2n1H+40Fte1J0a3YAO6yp810n1EH1qugKi6XYdXB2Yqp32JE7DlOtW1LixLWhwzk+ysR9aBHRuJRzcdXRpeOywOigAbGqsVhluDK4kTMVNgLCXLSMyhplhmAMZiW5eP0pjdHpwBH5WYfY0HeCwiWlCW1CqCSANhJk/U1Fi7hLXGXdQLaeDORmPp2PY86q/Y2+G7cHnlb7rWdbS5KwUcNdc6gqeyCASwMaERGXjQaX7ChVRHcACkaEAciNaX+Lb/6q89A489lb0j1pgv3Bvbn8rA+0xXhxwHeS4P5SQPVZFB6HS8pXfmNQynhI3U8RSg3+Td7QYEKx2cRqpjZo99xsQOL16y5EuqtsDOR/SYJ8tq9uo2Uqw65PDRx7QCRvIg7acaDhnOSDq1p0nxEgBj5qZ8waa17K9598oRQOJOrADXjnA9Kzoa7nVSD2Tbd2EaEEqGWJ6xTw0EMdpEMvh0h2Nt1DFiw7KhjAUuCTCATrJ9KCy2TbUIAGutLEbCT3mJ4KNvYU1AtlS7sJPedoEnh5DgB48amw2aCUEFtWu3ARPkmhgcASAJ48ewbKNL3Az79tgW/lUbegoGi879xco+Zx9k394ruzglUhjLN8zan04L6AVyuPX4VuN5I33IFejEudrTD8zKPsT/YoI2XIY/0nBH5LmntM/wBNaprHxtm675CbadZbdDAZ52idViJbnuapwtp7iK5uuMyq0LlESJgHLJGvPhQd2ejUVgygyM0SSQMxJaBwkmjpVwLTyyrAkFiAAV7Q38QK6OATjmbzZj9JimW8FbGoRQdpgT770EvRuKR7lzIcykW7kjbtgiAdj3Z341pVk9GEk2W3BsnUbGCnCtagKkxY/Es+DN/42quouknC9W5k5XGwJPaBXZQSd6Drolps2iOKL9qku9HubjOHMG5bcCW0CrlZY2g7xtXWBxD5MotN2Sw1KqNGMDvHhFUFrx2W2vmSfsBQWVl4TvWztrfGumuefsCaeLV073QPyIAfQsWH0rO/ZQD2mdst2DmaARcEbLA+LgBQbTOBuQPOpz0ha+dT5GftXa4G3vkWeZEn601iqgnRQPICgm/bA21u43OUy/8AfE+lfNf4w6X/AGOz1q4RbhDKOrR8rHMYUgIpntZR68dju4rpBzC2QMz6KzyAebBd2AGvAHTXWlWsGtowC168+pa5E/mIUAIo8B4DWtcaiYmYvwZ/QVy9dtOL1lbbZ1fqmuF2KtrDkqNNIB1BKkcK0L/ZS8xSBcXKtvSXaGB0Xi0qNOC0nF4bvkMSyA9ucpa64AABB7IUHRdpYfLXd/DqGZnlgjZWzEmEYAggkyuUwZEQM1ScjvC2wwnKl2NCc7TIicyuOyfA6irEvBBHUugHyqCPQLqfakG12glyc2yXR2S3gSPiHI6HluA/rLid4dYvNRDAeK/F/L7VB0OkbfFsvg4Kx5hgIpyXlbVWBHgQaLN5XBykMNiOXgRwPga8fB2yZKLPOBPvQKvn8W0PB/sK86EWMPYHEWrY9kFZ+NsAG51ZZSlvKMrNGe4YWdYkQpPg4q9MI6AKl0wIHbVTAGgAyhf1oE9J4K496xcR8q282ZeDSUgxxIAYDUd/jsdMVHN4cLbf1L958KLmLdQS1ptBPZZTt5kUE/RZlbGkfhsY5SUrVrH6IILIAGGSyoOZSD2zIgkQ3dMxPCtigKl6UH4TECSsMBzKnN+lVV4woI8I4z3FGxyup5hhz46g+4pfTOKe3bLoATIGuwk6k6jQeJApFjsFP+mTaM/K0G2Z/pHqa1HYAEkwBxOkUHGFulkViCpZQSDIKkiYIIBBHjUePtgMZOVbilGbbKyyUP1b1C039rZ/3SyPnaQvpxbzGnjXN3owMPxGLtwJ0CncFVGgg7bnmTQLwuPa4oNtROzM2igjeBuw3IOgI1mqLeBE5nJdubbD8q7L9TzJqS3iCpLtoNFvD5WGzj+Ejc8oPA1biMTEKkM52HAD5mjYfegka9+M+XtPARV4LHadidwJKg88ginEdUjN33ManQux0UeAnQDgK46Hw+VXbdndmZtJbWBtsIAgcKYvbu/w2/q5+2Ue5bwFWcji5ZypbtzmJdcx2LGc7H3E+VMAHXODqHRTHAwWDT6FR6V7f1u2xyDt66KJ/qb2ov6XbZ5h185AYfY1ArDWwVay+uTTXcqdUad50ieamu7F0owt3DM91/m8DwDffhRjuwVujZdG/IdyfIwfATVF60HBVhIP978PMUC7+DVjmghvmXRvfj5GRSmvPbnOA6AEl10IA4svH+X2rqxeZCLdwzPcf5vBuTffhxFKxt4MSD+7SC5jvH4UHMzuPIcaCfB3BcKQQcxN1/4QNEVuR8D8jcq2DWfZ6PBm4wK3WMkqYIjuryYAaQZG9N624nfGcfMg1jmV4/yz5UGb0b0rde6EdAo7UwG4FhmzHTLoBtMmZ4VpdJa2yvzkJ/UYPlpPtT7N5XEqQw8P15HwqPGXocncWlLRzdtEA5mJ0/jFA7B6tcfm0DyUR7TmPqasqfBWciKpMkDU8ydWPvNUUBRRRQZfSlogyACrjq3kxEnsNI10JI/mFGBs5v3p6x1MMDooI4hdhIgiZOtaF62GBU6giCPOstXZTJkvbADwNblvXKwHxEa7ccwG4oK+kcWbaqwEy6JvEB2Cz4xO1I/w/wBK/tNoXChTbsncSAYJ2kTB5EEVo23DAEEEHUEbGkYrEZSEQAudhwA4s0bD70E3SUhl6sA3ojKdmXj1nIcjvJ03NTdGxaBjMy6ZxHbtkcCBunIDYbSNtTC4cKN8zHVmO7H9ByHCucThQxzAlWGzD7EbMPA/SgiwN8JYGXKzAlQAdCxY5dRwMg+VaGEs5FC7niTxJ1J9TXzuJDC8b0FAnZdra5ldjuzoRIyD4h8zyRArXw2MZlzAJdHO2d+GgYx9eFa5bDrYm+5+VEHuWP8AxRjtMjcnXXkD2f1j1qfB4wZrhK3AS+3VuYhVG6gg+ho6Uxg6p4FwsFLLFu4e0vaXZeYGlZGkw0qPAHKGtHe3AE8UPdP0In+GhsWxEqkL8zsoBG4IgkxHOKy8WcxFwk3cmjBRlthDE5j8cRmiTEba6hbjb4uIwBAt/FcOw/8Aj5t/FsDzNIwFshkW4CqD9zPxHnc5XI4HxO8hdCxhTIa4QxGwAhV5ZRz8T9Kdesq6lWEg/wBjyPjQMbbTU1j9C9Mm+wVlCk2luCGDbhc0x3dWgTEwSNjVti8yMLdwzPcf5vBuTffhxqsigkx9hADcllYa5k7x5CNm5QQaiwVtywR4JEXHYcWI7KkbaROh+FdppuJxGY5olUMIB/mXOHovPnJ+HW3CWMq6mWOrHmTvHhwA5UFFFFFAUUUUBUuLwxaGUw6yVPDXcHmp0nyB4VVRQYX7b1chBvOZD/knixj4NQdPMaExq4OwFBM5i2rN8x/QchXGJwknOhCuBE8GHysOI5cuFSYZypYIpndrJIkfxWidCDy2/KZFA/F2Ha7ZKkhVLF4YidIVSo0YEknXbKOdOxd7Iuglicqjmx29OJ8BXeHxCuJUzwPAg8iDqD4Gp7Zz3S3w2+yPFviPoIA82oIOjuibqHt3ywDTuwkazorKFmeR29psN/h1lYnOslSoaCSJIKkSfhg8dc3gKu6ZS/KG1myw2cLlk7RBbUHcCCNzvpDs9xcNNwgXRaGYr8+WCR/NQSf4Z6MNvC2F6y4T1ay2YmZ1mHLa61ojBGIa7db1C/8AjVaegCKABooiPIeNJ6PxoupmylTLKVaJBUkHYxwoJui8EnVoSskADtSx7OnxcdK0jG1S4AQHXk7fUz+tQ27WIN8FiwQXHIIIAKZFCqVG8sWMnXsnXUUFvR7Zc1k/BBHihnL7QV/lpd6zcOIRhmFsKc3b0J1gZPWc2/ZAGk13jlyxdEym/ih72g3jQ+lVNeUDMSAN5JEe9BzftK6lWEg8P7286ybuLIm0zdgSDd2mPg016yNyPTtaB+JxJYT2ktnbQh7ngg3Xz0PlvTcNhCSGcBQvctjZPE8Gbx2HDiSHuDw5JDlcsCET5F8hpmOk8tuc314BXtAUUUUBRRRQFFFFAVPicKrgTMjYgwV8iNqoooMXHWXUZoLOBC3EgMOALrswG5AB/LTMFeKoAoF1R8Sd7xLKTvMzB9K1qmv4NGMkEN8ykqfca+lAW8YjaBhPI6H2OtL6R7oX5mUa8RmkjbkDXNzCvEZluDlcUT7rH2qK/gmlItuADP4VzbsmCEchRrHA0G0VB3rjD4dUGVFCqNgBArO6xh2c2IU762w8eqqR9a8W62zXL5nQRZj65IHmaCrDt+LdXmEf3DLH+w+9Ov4lE7zAeuvtWU2GcuDlvEBWHbuKgOqx+6bXZtxx4bVXbwbju9Xb37q5j7nT6Gg6fFkiVSB89zsr7HtH2FZ+AssdAOsynsXHEW1GkZEG8bA8l71aiYFZzNLtzcz7Dur6AbCqgKCbD4QKcxJZ/mP2A2UeA9ZqkCvaKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooCiiigKKKKAooooP/2Q==";
String header = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";

String encodedImage = dataUrl.substring(header.length());

byte[] imageData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedImage);
```

From here you can do what you want, for instance you can print image on screen

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));      
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```